# Run Macro of invisible Word Application

Tags: vba, ms-word

My problem is that I am trying to execute a function that is located in a Word document. The Word application is not visible. If the application is made visible just before and invisible right after the command, ".Application.Run "GenerateQRCode", wordDocument" works as expected. But it should work without the document or application being visible. If I run it without making the application visible this message appears: Object does not support this property or method. 
Code that works:

```
'Creates a document from a template which is not visible
wordDocument=WordMod.Application.Documents.Add (documentTemplatePath, , _
                WdNewDocumentType.wdNewBlankDocument, showWord)
wordDocument.Application.Visible = True
WordMod.Application.Run "GenerateQRCode", wordDocument
wordDocument.Application.Visible = False
```

Code that not works:

```
wordDocument.Application.Visible = False
WordMod.Application.Run "GenerateQRCode", wordDocument
```

When the application is not visible it does not work with the ".Run" how can i fix it?

Comment: More code would be helpful here. Not sure your question is a [reprex] yet.

Comment: What is the code for `GenerateQRCode`? Is it a macro in the *Word* document, or in some other program? What application does `Application` refer to?

Comment: GenerateQRCode is the function of the word template and is used to generate a QR Code in the new document (created from the template)

Comment: Then what does `Application` refer to? Where is this code hosted - in Excel? `Application` refers to the *host* program.

Comment: Sorry my fault, i forgot some code :/. I will add it. Yes it is in Excel but i have a Modul for the application

Comment: Then we need the code for `GenerateQRCode` to be able to debug.

Comment: I suppose the problem lies in the code of the `GenerateQRCode` function. Just try to create a new public sub and run it programmatically when Word is not visible, does it work?

Comment: Without knowing what's in your GenerateQRCode sub it's impossible to diagnose the problem. For all we know the code there relies on the document being visible.